# If the denominator of an irreducible fraction is 990, the length of repedent must be 2 when this fraction is changed to repeating decimal?

Tags: number-theory

It is easy to show that 0.10404... (repedent : 04) is 104-1/990 = 103/990.

But it is quiet difficult for me to show that
'if the denominator of an irreducible fraction is 990, the length of repedent must be 2 when this fraction is changed to repeating decimal' is true or not.

Interestingly, I think this question is related to number theory although it is about to rational number.

I'd like to know a proof if it is true or some couterexamples if it is false.

Comment: It just comes down to decimals of the form $0.\overline{ab}=\frac{ab}{99}$, so to push the repetition back, you have to multiply the denominator by $10$

Comment: The condition is the denominator of 'Irreducible fraction' is 990.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/990 = .001010101...

If you multiply this by any whole number from 1-99, it will repeat that whole number over two digits.  For example,

57/990 = .057575757...

99/990 Does not repeat.

99/990 = .1

No matter what fraction you have, you can 'break off' as many 99/990 as needed to make it 99n/990 + a/990 where a will be less than 99.  For example,

577/990 = 5*99/990 + 82/990 = 5*.1 + .0828282...

Since the part broken off will always be a non-repeating multiple of .1, the repeating part will always be 2 digits.

Comment: I think you mean $0.0010101...$

Comment: Thanks; edited.